# How do you limit UILabel characters in swift?

Tags: swift, uilabel, character-limit

I'm trying to set a limit in my label to 10 characters, I'm a complete newbie to programming in general so its my 3rd month so far... anyway thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Not even close to enough information and no code.

Comment: Since you've already set a limit on yourself how can you expect to set one on a `UILabel`?

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear and don't need code just to limit characters on one label... It's not like I'm asking how to write a complicated function and  then the code be necessary

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to limit the UILabel to just 10 characters then
you just have to assign it with a text with length of 10.
You can use `NSString` and `NSRange` to extract the text you need.

```
let str = "This is a Very Long Label"
let nsString = str as NSString
if nsString.length >= 10
{
  label.text = nsString.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length > 10 ? 10 : nsString.length))
}
```

Comment: Of course this code will crash if `str` has less than 10 characters in it to start with.

Answer (score 14):

You can also create a `String` extension and reuse it with any text string.. You can do it in the following way:

create the extension:

```
extension String {
   func maxLength(length: Int) -> String {
       var str = self
       let nsString = str as NSString
       if nsString.length >= length {
           str = nsString.substring(with:
               NSRange(
                location: 0,
                length: nsString.length > length ? length : nsString.length)
           )
       }
       return  str
   }
}
```

you can use the extension in the following way:

```
label.text = "This is a Very Long Label".maxLength(length: 10)
```

the previous code was tested in **Swift 5.0**

Answer (score 2):

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39677331/2548473

My version is (**Swift 5+**):

```swift
extension String {
    func shorted(to symbols: Int) -> String {
        guard self.count > symbols else {
            return self
        }
        return self.prefix(symbols) + " ..."
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

SWIFT 3

```
        let str = GL_GetNews[indexPath.row]["n_body"].stringValue
        let nsString = str as NSString
        if nsString.length > 0
        {
             cell.newsDescription.text = nsString.substring(with: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length > 200 ? 200 : nsString.length))
        }
```