# How does String substring work in Swift

Tags: swift, string, range, substring

I've been updating some of my old code and answers with Swift 3 but when I got to Swift Strings and Indexing with substrings things got confusing.

Specifically I was trying the following:

```
let str = "Hello, playground"
let prefixRange = str.startIndex..<str.startIndex.advancedBy(5)
let prefix = str.substringWithRange(prefixRange)
```

where the second line was giving me the following error

> Value of type 'String' has no member 'substringWithRange'

I see that `String` does have the following methods now:

```
str.substring(to: String.Index)
str.substring(from: String.Index)
str.substring(with: Range<String.Index>)
```

These were really confusing me at first so I started playing around [index and range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676939/how-does-string-index-work-in-swift-3). This is a followup question and answer for substring. I am adding an answer below to show how they are used.

Comment: For those who want to get the substring from the string https://stackoverflow.com/q/32305891/468724

Comment: or subscript string or substring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language/38215613

Answer (score 1055, accepted):

[image]

All of the following examples use

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
```

## Swift 4

Strings got a pretty big overhaul in Swift 4. When you get some substring from a String now, you get a `Substring` type back rather than a `String`. Why is this? Strings are value types in Swift. That means if you use one String to make a new one, then it has to be copied over. This is good for stability (no one else is going to change it without your knowledge) but bad for efficiency.

A Substring, on the other hand, is a reference back to the original String from which it came. Here is an image from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) illustrating that.

[image]

No copying is needed so it is much more efficient to use. However, imagine you got a ten character Substring from a million character String. Because the Substring is referencing the String, the system would have to hold on to the entire String for as long as the Substring is around. Thus, whenever you are done manipulating your Substring, convert it to a String.

```
let myString = String(mySubstring)
```

This will copy just the substring over and the memory holding old String can be [reclaimed](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). Substrings (as a type) are meant to be short lived.

Another big improvement in Swift 4 is that Strings are Collections (again). That means that whatever you can do to a Collection, you can do to a String (use subscripts, iterate over the characters, filter, etc).

The following examples show how to get a substring in Swift.

## Getting substrings

You can get a substring from a string by using subscripts or a number of other methods (for example, `prefix`, `suffix`, `split`). You still need to use `String.Index` and not an `Int` index for the range, though. (See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676940/3681880) if you need help with that.)

#### Beginning of a string

You can use a subscript (note the Swift 4 one-sided range):

```
let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
let mySubstring = str[..<index] // Hello
```

or `prefix`:

```
let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
let mySubstring = str.prefix(upTo: index) // Hello
```

or even easier:

```
let mySubstring = str.prefix(5) // Hello
```

#### End of a string

Using subscripts:

```
let index = str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: -10)
let mySubstring = str[index...] // playground
```

or `suffix`:

```
let index = str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: -10)
let mySubstring = str.suffix(from: index) // playground
```

or even easier:

```
let mySubstring = str.suffix(10) // playground
```

Note that when using the `suffix(from: index)` I had to count back from the end by using `-10`. That is not necessary when just using `suffix(x)`, which just takes the last `x` characters of a String.

#### Range in a string

Again we simply use subscripts here.

```
let start = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
let end = str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: -6)
let range = start..<end

let mySubstring = str[range]  // play
```

#### Converting `Substring` to `String`

Don't forget, when you are ready to save your substring, you should convert it to a `String` so that the old string's memory can be cleaned up.

```
let myString = String(mySubstring)
```

## Using an `Int` index extension?

I'm hesitant to use an `Int` based index extension after reading the article [*Strings in Swift 3*](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/08/swift-3-strings/) by Airspeed Velocity and Ole Begemann. Although in Swift 4, Strings are collections, the Swift team purposely hasn't used `Int` indexes. It is still `String.Index`. This has to do with Swift Characters being composed of varying numbers of Unicode codepoints. The actual index has to be uniquely calculated for every string.

I have to say, I hope the Swift team finds a way to abstract away `String.Index` in the future. But until then, I am choosing to use their API. It helps me to remember that String manipulations are not just simple `Int` index lookups.

Comment: Thx for the desctription. Well deserved uprates. Apple overcomplicated this. Substring should be as easy as string.substring[from...to].

Comment: Really good explanation . except one little thing `garbage collected` ;-) I hope people here know that there is no garbage collection in Swift.

Comment: @ChristianAnchorDampf, Thanks for taking the time to comment. I took out garbage collecting. How is the new wording?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Totally agree with @Teddy - unicode width should be implementation details, as most people don't care about how the bytes actually look like. The API design should be around 95% use cases, and provide low level APIs for people who needs to deal with protocol stack etc.

Comment: @superarts.org I like Dart's implementation. By default you can use integer indexing, but when you want to support emojis and other user input you can use the [Characters](https://pub.dev/packages/characters) package.

Comment: Apple has really made an awful mess of strings. They should not keep changing them between versions of Swift and you should not have to create extensions to do simple things like substring(). This should be built into the language.

Comment: If you have " No 'prefix' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'String' " error, then just cast it to a new string like this: String(str.prefix(5))

Comment: @Suragch What is `Int index extension` in your answer? Do you mean `str.suffix(10)` isn't safe? Or, maybe, the extension answered by @Code Different is the `Int index extension`. But each `Int` of the parameters of the extension is converted to `String.index` by `index(from:)` inside the functions. Isn't it safe?

Answer (score 296):

I'm really frustrated at Swift's String access model: everything has to be an `Index`. All I want is to access the i-th character of the string using `Int`, not the clumsy index and advancing (which happens to change with every major release). So I made an extension to `String`:

```
extension String {
    func index(from: Int) -> Index {
        return self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: from)
    }

    func substring(from: Int) -> String {
        let fromIndex = index(from: from)
        return String(self[fromIndex...])
    }

    func substring(to: Int) -> String {
        let toIndex = index(from: to)
        return String(self[..<toIndex])
    }

    func substring(with r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let startIndex = index(from: r.lowerBound)
        let endIndex = index(from: r.upperBound)
        return String(self[startIndex..<endIndex])
    }
}

let str = "Hello, playground"
print(str.substring(from: 7))         // playground
print(str.substring(to: 5))           // Hello
print(str.substring(with: 7..<11))    // play
```

Comment: The indexes are very useful because a *character* can be more than one byte. Try `let str = "Hello"` `print(str.substring(to: 2))`

Comment: Yes, I understand that a character (i.e. *extended grapheme cluster*) can take multiple bytes. My frustration is why we have to use the verbose index-advancing method to access the characters of a string. Why can't the Swift team just add some overloads to the Core Library to abstract it away. If I type `str[5]`, I want to access the character at index 5, whatever that character appears to be or how many bytes it takes. Isn't Swift all about developer's productivity?

Comment: nice utility.

I've added this for NSRange.
`func substring(with r: NSRange) -> String {
        return substring(with: r.location..<(r.location + r.length))
    }`

Comment: @CodeDifferent you say "I want to access the character at index 5, whatever that character appears to be or how many bytes it takes"... but in which encoding?

Comment: @vadian, Your example string is [a problem with Unicode and Swift itself](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41608512/), not a problem with the author's extension. However, there are [other issues to consider](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/08/swift-3-strings/) when being temped to abstract the complexity away in an extension.

Comment: I agree that Swift's designers made a big mistake in implementing String so that numeric indexing is not possible. They could have supported Unicode with all its bells and whistles and still have provided numeric indexing by adding a character lookup table alongside the string data. This lookup table could actually be non-existent for strings without problematic Unicode characters, and be created on-the-fly when needed. When it did exist it could, with fancy programming, be a segmented table so it only existed for the problematic sections of the string, so the extra storage would be minimal.

Comment: @RenniePet I believe Apple recognizes the problem and changes are coming. As per the Swift Evolution page on GitHub: "Swift 4 seeks to make strings more powerful and easier-to-use, while retaining Unicode correctness by default". It's vague but let's keep our hopes up

Comment: I think there are just too many C and C++ purists on the team who will say "Stirng is a collection of bytes" instead of "String is a collection of characters" and we end up with this mess. I understand there are probably some people who need access to bytes in String, but why not agree that the are minority and just provide them with appropriate and properly named methods to do so? Whoever is coming to Swift [and please admit, Apple invests in Swift to bring NEW developers] they expect someString[20] to be the 20th CHARACTER of the string, not 20th BYTE!

Comment: Looking for an opinion (and knowing that Swift 4 has already changed things)... In `index(from:)`, what about `return self.index(from >= 0 ? startIndex : endIndex, offsetBy: from)` to enable negative indices (i.e., offset from the end)? No need to be gentle; I can take it.

Comment: +1 I like this but my only gripe is that "to" is non-inclusive. In natural language, we don't say I'm going from A to B and then stop short of B. I feel your "to:" method need to add 1 when creating the index. Hence str.substring(to: 4) == "Hello".

Comment: C-R-A-S-H   MAY OCCUR, Will always crash if the requested index is beyond the string endIndex limit. this may be fixed with the following code: func index(from: Int) -> Index {
        if let index = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: from, limitedBy: self.endIndex) {
            return index
        }
        return self.endIndex
    }

Comment: @CodeDifferent why apple didn't add subscript character access? So that people understand that it's bad thing to do. Basically if you would do for i in 0..string.count using subscripts that would be double loop, cause under the hood index has to go through each byte of string to find out which is the next character. If you loop using index, you iterate over string only once. Btw, hate this myself, but that's the reasoning behind subscript being not available on string in swift.

Comment: @RaimundasSakalauskas that argument doesn't fly by me. C# has both Unicode correctness and integer subscripting, which is really convenient.  In Swift 1, Apple wanted developers to use `countElement(str)` to find the length. In Swift 3, Apple made string not conforming to `Sequence` and forced everyone to use `str.characters` instead. These guys are not afraid of making changes. Their stubbornness on integer subscripting in really hard to understand

Comment: @CodeDifferent Excerpt from documentation: "As mentioned above, different characters can require different amounts of memory to store, so in order to determine which Character is at a particular position, you must iterate over each Unicode scalar from the start or end of that String. For this reason, Swift strings can’t be indexed by integer values.". If you add popular string extension, essentially you are doing nested loop accessing particular character. To avoid devs using that, they opted not to add this as language element. Especially to prevent loop within loop.

Comment: It's not taht it's impossible, but this has some real performance penalty, and if for i in 0..string.count would be available, people would simply do that without giving it a second thought. Now when it's not available SOME read to the point to understand why it isn't available.

Comment: Is it possible that every 6 months (each time a new Swift version is released) the geniuses at Apple can come up with yet a new-and-better way of handling something as basic as Strings???

Comment: @IgnacioOroná they have a [String Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/StringManifesto.md) for what they want Swift strings to be. Still no integer indexing on the table. And my other gripe: no raw string so regex pattern is so painful. To match a single backslash I'd have to write `\\\\ `

Comment: Swift is not only not swift, but also not smart regarding strings. That's crazy, that there is no method available to find an index of a substring in a string! Apple, are you OK?

Comment: This unnecessarily offsets both range's upper and lower bound from the start. This is extremely inefficient. You could simply offset the range count from the start instead of offsetting from the startIndex again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language/38215613. I have already fixed that issue on the accepted answer there as well. Another point is that you should be extending StringProtocol and returning a subsequence

Comment: How can anyone defend Apple on this one? This system is so unbelievably cumbersome and is so different than any other language.

Comment: @Krystian Your assessment is totally wrong. C and C++ treats strings as runs of bytes. Swift doesn't. Swift strings are collections of `Character`, which are unicode correct.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica better check when my comment was made and what it was about. It was made 3 years ago and what it was about before you start commenting my assessments.

Comment: @Krystian Yep. April 2017 was around the time of Swift 3.1. The behavior that's now directly on `String` used to be contained in a `characters: CharacterView` property, but the functionality was largely the same. `someString[20] to be the 20th CHARACTER of the string, not 20th BYTE!` Indexing a string doesn't return a byte, or code point, or anything less than a proper extended grapheme cluster (`Character`) and it never has. The Swift 3.1 String subscript operator took a `String.Index` and returned a `Character`: https://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/type/string/#subscript-subscript_-string-index

Comment: This is half the reason I quit using Swift. It's too complicated to deal with strings in this language, and I don't buy any of these excuses cause in other languages it's a million times easier.

Comment: That's a not bad extension, would be nicer something like the PHP equiv.  Personally I find swift string handling a pain and the language itself is so inferior to Kotlin (I'm forced to do both ios and Android, but naturally prefer Android).

Answer (score 191):

Swift 5 Extension:

```
extension String {
    subscript(_ range: CountableRange<Int>) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: max(0, range.lowerBound))
        let end = index(start, offsetBy: min(self.count - range.lowerBound, 
                                             range.upperBound - range.lowerBound))
        return String(self[start..<end])
    }

    subscript(_ range: CountablePartialRangeFrom<Int>) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: max(0, range.lowerBound))
         return String(self[start...])
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let s = "hello"
s[0..<3] // "hel"
s[3...]  // "lo"
```

Or unicode:

```
let s = ""
s[0..<1] // ""
```

Comment: So much better, thank you for posting this extension! I think coming from Python, Swift is much harder than necessary to get used to. It seems for people going in the other direction from Objective C to Swift there is more positive confirmation.

Comment: What's the purpose of the count which returns count?

Comment: @Leon I just removed it. Prior to 4.1, `count` was only available on `self.characters`

Comment: Great solution! One wonders why Apple didn't implement anything like that on first instance..

Comment: Are there any gotchas to watch out with this particular extension? Why didn't Apple do something like this?

Comment: @Andz it is very inefficient. It starts from the beginning of the string - twice - and has to parse every character from there to "range" - twice.

Comment: You'll also need to add [an extension that takes a `CountableClosedRange<Int>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46627527/709202) if you'd like to write e.g. `s[0...2]`.

Comment: @ChrisFrederick and `CountablePartialRangeFrom<Int>` for s[2...].

Comment: I'd put a guard at the beginning of your subscript to avoid potential crashes. Like so: guard range.lowerBound < count, range.lowerBound >= 0 else { return self }

Comment: This unnecessarily offsets both range's upper and lower bound from the start. This is extremely inefficient. You could simply offset the range count from the start instead of offsetting from the startIndex again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092884/get-nth-character-of-a-string-in-swift-programming-language/38215613. I have already fixed that issue on the accepted answer there as well. Another point is that you should be extending StringProtocol and returning a subsequence

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the critique!

Comment: Actually works fine, Swift 4.2.1 from Xcode 10.1, last High Sierra 10.13.6 version!

Comment: 'subscript(_:)' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an integer range, use a String.Index range instead.

Answer (score 39):

**Swift 4 & 5:**

```
extension String {
  subscript(_ i: Int) -> String {
    let idx1 = index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)
    let idx2 = index(idx1, offsetBy: 1)
    return String(self[idx1..<idx2])
  }

  subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
    let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: r.lowerBound)
    let end = index(startIndex, offsetBy: r.upperBound)
    return String(self[start ..< end])
  }

  subscript (r: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> String {
    let startIndex =  self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: r.lowerBound)
    let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: r.upperBound - r.lowerBound)
    return String(self[startIndex...endIndex])
  }
}
```

How to use it:

> "abcde"[0] --> "a"
>
> "abcde"[0...2] --> "abc"
>
> "abcde"[2..<4] --> "cd"

Answer (score 24):

## Swift 4

In swift 4 `String` conforms to `Collection`. Instead of `substring`, we should now use a `subscript.` So if you want to cut out only the word `"play"` from `"Hello, playground"`, you could do it like this:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
let start = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
let end = str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: -6)
let result = str[start..<end] // The result is of type Substring
```

It is interesting to know, that doing so will give you a `Substring` instead of a `String`. This is fast and efficient as `Substring` shares its storage with the original String. However sharing memory this way can also easily lead to memory leaks.

This is why you should copy the result into a new String, once you want to clean up the original String. You can do this using the normal constructor:

```
let newString = String(result)
```

You can find more information on the new `Substring` class in the [Apple documentation].[1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/substring)

So, if you for example get a `Range` as the result of an `NSRegularExpression`, you could use the following extension:

```
extension String {

    subscript(_ range: NSRange) -> String {
        let start = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
        let end = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)
        let subString = self[start..<end]
        return String(subString)
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code will crash if range.upperBound is > length of string.  Also, a sample usage would have been helpful as well, as I wasn't familiar with subscripts in Swift. You could include something like datePartOnly = "2018-01-04-08:00"[NSMakeRange(0, 10)].  Other than that, very nice answer, +1 :).

Comment: nowadays it is this weird thing:  `text[Range( nsRange , in: text)!]`

Answer (score 17):

Came across this fairly short and simple way of achieving this.

```
var str = "Hello, World"
let arrStr = Array(str)
print(arrStr[0..<5]) //["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
print(arrStr[7..<12]) //["W", "o", "r", "l", "d"]
print(String(arrStr[0..<5])) //Hello
print(String(arrStr[7..<12])) //World
```

Comment: Thx, geeeeeeez, could Apple made substrings any more complicated?! This probably isn't the most performant solution but in my case the code will be hardly ever called so it's a good compromise for readablility.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a function that returns substring of a given substring when start and end indices are provided. For complete reference you can visit the links given below.

```
func substring(string: String, fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int) -> String? {
    if fromIndex < toIndex && toIndex < string.count /*use string.characters.count for swift3*/{
        let startIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: fromIndex)
        let endIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: toIndex)
        return String(string[startIndex..<endIndex])
    }else{
        return nil
    }
}
```

Here's a link to the blog post that I have created to deal with string manipulation in swift. 
[String manipulation in swift (Covers swift 4 as well)](https://nikeskrjha.blogspot.com/2017/08/working-with-strings-in-swift.html)

[Or you can see this gist on github](https://gist.github.com/nikeshkrjha/b380b27d37324a0db288afe9c5507b01#file-stringscharactersdemo-swift)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same initial reaction.  I too was frustrated at how syntax and objects change so drastically in every major release.

However, I realized from experience how I always eventually suffer the consequences of trying to fight "change" like dealing with multi-byte characters which is inevitable if you're looking at a global audience.

So I decided to recognize and respect the efforts exerted by Apple engineers and do my part by understanding their mindset when they came up with this "horrific" approach.

Instead of creating extensions which is just a workaround to make your life easier (I'm not saying they're wrong or expensive), why not figure out how Strings are now designed to work.

For instance, I had this code which was working on Swift 2.2:

```
let rString = cString.substringToIndex(2)
let gString = (cString.substringFromIndex(2) as NSString).substringToIndex(2)
let bString = (cString.substringFromIndex(4) as NSString).substringToIndex(2)
```

and after giving up trying to get the same approach working e.g. using Substrings, I finally understood the concept of treating Strings as a bidirectional collection for which I ended up with this version of the same code:

```
let rString = String(cString.characters.prefix(2))
cString = String(cString.characters.dropFirst(2))
let gString = String(cString.characters.prefix(2))
cString = String(cString.characters.dropFirst(2))
let bString = String(cString.characters.prefix(2))
```

I hope this contributes...

Comment: Well, dealing with a complex problem does not mean that the solution could be elegant. Again, I also understand the problem, but the entire String class and dealing with it is just horrible.

Answer (score 8):

I'm quite mechanical thinking. Here are the basics...

**Swift 4**
**Swift 5**

```
  let t = "abracadabra"

  let start1 = t.index(t.startIndex, offsetBy:0)
  let   end1 = t.index(t.endIndex, offsetBy:-5)
  let start2 = t.index(t.endIndex, offsetBy:-5)
  let   end2 = t.index(t.endIndex, offsetBy:0)

  let t2 = t[start1 ..< end1]
  let t3 = t[start2 ..< end2]                

  //or a shorter form 

  let t4 = t[..<end1]
  let t5 = t[start2...]

  print("\(t2) \(t3) \(t)")
  print("\(t4) \(t5) \(t)")

  // result:
  // abraca dabra abracadabra
```

The result is a substring, meaning that it is a part of the original string. To get a full blown separate string just use e.g.

```
    String(t3)
    String(t4)
```

This is what I use:

```
    let mid = t.index(t.endIndex, offsetBy:-5)
    let firstHalf = t[..<mid]
    let secondHalf = t[mid...]
```

Answer (score 7):

## Swift 5

// imagine, need make substring from 2, length 3

```
let s = "abcdef"    
let subs = s.suffix(s.count-2).prefix(3)
```

// now subs = "cde"

Answer (score 6):

I am new in Swift 3, but looking the `String` (index) syntax for analogy I think that index is like a "pointer" constrained to string and Int can help as an independent object. Using the base + offset syntax , then  we can get the i-th character from string with the code bellow:

```
let s = "abcdefghi"
let i = 2
print (s[s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy:i)])
// print c
```

For a range of characters ( indexes) from string using String (range) syntax we can get from i-th to f-th characters with the code bellow:

```
let f = 6
print (s[s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy:i )..<s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy:f+1 )])
//print cdefg
```

For a substring (range) from a string using String.substring (range) we can get the substring using the code bellow:

```
print (s.substring (with:s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy:i )..<s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy:f+1 ) ) )
//print cdefg
```

Notes:

1. The i-th and f-th begin with 0.
2. To f-th, I use offsetBY: f + 1, because the range of subscription use ..< (half-open operator), not include the f-th position.
3. Of course must include validate errors like invalid index.

Answer (score 6):

I created an simple function like this:

```
func sliceString(str: String, start: Int, end: Int) -> String {
    let data = Array(str)
    return String(data[start..<end])
}
```

you can use it in following way

```
print(sliceString(str: "0123456789", start: 0, end: 3)) // -> prints 012
```

Comment: Now as an extension...

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4+**

```
extension String {
    func take(_ n: Int) -> String {
        guard n >= 0 else {
            fatalError("n should never negative")
        }
        let index = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: min(n, self.count))
        return String(self[..<index])
    }
}
```

Returns a subsequence of the first n characters, or the entire string if the string is shorter. (inspired by: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/take.html)

Example:

```
let text = "Hello, World!"
let substring = text.take(5) //Hello
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

```
extension String {
    subscript(_ i: Int) -> String {
        let idx1 = index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)
        let idx2 = index(idx1, offsetBy: 1)
        return String(self[idx1..<idx2])
    }
}

let s = "hello"

s[0]    // h
s[1]    // e
s[2]    // l
s[3]    // l
s[4]    // o
```

Comment: Now try this in a string of a million characters.

Comment: why? what happens?

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple extension for this (Swift 3)

```
extension String {
    func substring(location: Int, length: Int) -> String? {
        guard characters.count >= location + length else { return nil }
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: location)
        let end = index(startIndex, offsetBy: location + length)
        return substring(with: start..<end)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Heres a more generic implementation:**

This technique still uses `index` to keep with Swift's standards, and imply a full Character.

```
extension String
{
    func subString <R> (_ range: R) -> String? where R : RangeExpression, String.Index == R.Bound
    {
        return String(self[range])
    }

    func index(at: Int) -> Index
    {
        return self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: at)
    }
}
```

To sub string from the 3rd character:

```
let item = "Fred looks funny"
item.subString(item.index(at: 2)...) // "ed looks funny"
```

I've used camel `subString` to indicate it returns a `String` and not a `Substring`.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the above I needed to split a string at a non-printing character dropping the non-printing character. I developed two methods:

```
var str = "abc\u{1A}12345sdf"
let range1: Range<String.Index> = str.range(of: "\u{1A}")!
let index1: Int = str.distance(from: str.startIndex, to: range1.lowerBound)
let start = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: index1)
let end = str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: -0)
let result = str[start..<end] // The result is of type Substring
let firstStr = str[str.startIndex..<range1.lowerBound]
```

which I put together using some of the answers above.

Because a String is a collection I then did the following:

```
var fString = String()
for (n,c) in str.enumerated(){

*if c == "\u{1A}" {
    print(fString);
    let lString = str.dropFirst(n + 1)
    print(lString)
    break
   }
 fString += String(c)
}*
```

Which for me was more intuitive. Which one is best? I have no way of telling
They both work with Swift 5

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is anything different about Strings in Swift 5? I haven't had time to play around with it yet.

Comment: They say so but I have not had a chance to look into it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "VEGANISM"
print (str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy:2)..<str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)] )

//Output-> GANIS
```

Here, `str.startIndex` and `str.endIndex` is the starting index and ending index of your string.

Here as the offsetBy in startIndex = 2 -> `str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy:2)` therefore the trimmed string will have starting from index 2 (i.e. from second character) and offsetBy in endIndex = -1 -> `str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)` i.e. 1 character is being trimmed from the end.

```
var str = "VEGANISM"
print (str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy:0)..<str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: 0)] )

//Output-> VEGANISM
```

As the `offsetBy value = 0` on both sides i.e., `str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy:0)` and `str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy: 0)` therefore, the complete string is being printed

Answer (score 2):

Who ever was responsible for strings in Swift made a total mess of it, and it is definitely one of the worst features of the language.

A simple work-around is the implement a function like this (or make it an extension function):

```
func substring(str: String, start: Int, end : Int) -> String
{
    let startIndex = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: start)
    let endIndex = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: end)
    return String(str[startIndex..<endIndex])
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of other answers including https://stackoverflow.com/a/45628909/20287183

Answer (score 2):

Tons of answers already, but here's a Swift 5 extension that works like `substring` in most other languages. `length` is optional, indexes are capped, and invalid selections result in an empty string (not an error or nil):

```
extension String {
    func substring(_ location: Int, _ length: Int? = nil) -> String {
      let start = min(max(0, location), self.count)
      let limitedLength = min(self.count - start, length ?? Int.max)
      let from = index(startIndex, offsetBy: start)
      let to = index(startIndex, offsetBy: start + limitedLength)
      return String(self[from..<to])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4

"Substring" (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/substring):

```
let greeting = "Hi there! It's nice to meet you! "
let endOfSentence = greeting.index(of: "!")!
let firstSentence = greeting[...endOfSentence]
// firstSentence == "Hi there!"
```

Example of extension String:

```
private typealias HowDoYouLikeThatElonMusk = String
private extension HowDoYouLikeThatElonMusk {

    subscript(_ from: Character?, _ to: Character?, _ include: Bool) -> String? {
        if let _from: Character = from, let _to: Character = to {
            let dynamicSourceForEnd: String = (_from == _to ? String(self.reversed()) : self)
            guard let startOfSentence: String.Index = self.index(of: _from),
                let endOfSentence: String.Index = dynamicSourceForEnd.index(of: _to) else {
                return nil
            }

            let result: String = String(self[startOfSentence...endOfSentence])
            if include == false {
                guard result.count > 2 else {
                        return nil
                }
                return String(result[result.index(result.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)..<result.index(result.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)])
            }
            return result
        } else if let _from: Character = from {
            guard let startOfSentence: String.Index = self.index(of: _from) else {
                return nil
            }
            let result: String = String(self[startOfSentence...])
            if include == false {
                guard result.count > 1 else {
                    return nil
                }
                return String(result[result.index(result.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)...])
            }
            return result
        } else if let _to: Character = to {
            guard let endOfSentence: String.Index = self.index(of: _to) else {
                    return nil
            }
            let result: String = String(self[...endOfSentence])
            if include == false {
                guard result.count > 1 else {
                    return nil
                }
                return String(result[..<result.index(result.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)])
            }
            return result
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

example of using the extension String:

```
let source =                                   ">>>01234..56789<<<"
// include = true
var from =          source["3", nil, true]  //       "34..56789<<<"
var to =            source[nil, "6", true]  // ">>>01234..56"
var fromTo =        source["3", "6", true]  //       "34..56"
let notFound =      source["a", nil, true]  // nil
// include = false
from =              source["3", nil, false] //        "4..56789<<<"
to =                source[nil, "6", false] // ">>>01234..5"
fromTo =            source["3", "6", false] //        "4..5"
let outOfBounds =   source[".", ".", false] // nil

let str = "Hello, playground"
let hello = str[nil, ",", false] // "Hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

The specificity of `String` has mostly been addressed in other answers. To paraphrase: `String` has a specific `Index` which is not of type `Int` because string elements do not have the same size in the general case. Hence, `String` does not conform to `RandomAccessCollection` and accessing a specific index implies the traversal of the collection, which is not an O(1) operation.

Many answers have proposed workarounds for using ranges, but they can lead to inefficient code as they use String methods (`index(from:)`, `index(:offsetBy:)`, ...) that are not O(1).

To access string elements like in an array you should use an `Array`:

```swift
let array = Array("Hello, world!")
let letter = array[5]
```

This is a trade-off, the array creation is an O(n) operation but array accesses are then O(1). You can convert back to a String when you want with `String(array)`.

Comment: This seems like it would be a good option if you are manipulating your own text. However, if it's coming from users, you run into problems with surrogate pairs and grapheme clusters.

Comment: Sure, this should be used with caution and the user must know what he is doing.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5 Solution High Performance**

```
let fromIndex = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: fromIndex)
let toIndex = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: toIndex)
```

I used this approach to get the substring from a `fromIndex` to `toIndex` for a Leetcode problem and it timed-out it seems like this is quite in-efficient and slow and was causing the timeout.

A faster pure Swift way to get this is done is:

```
let fromIndex = String.Index(utf16Offset:fromIndex, in: s)
let toIndex = String.Index(utf16Offset: toIndex, in: s)
```

Comment: This gives unexpected results if there are any characters in the string that are made up of multiple unicode codepoints (emojis for example).  The UTF16 index does not map to the character index in this case. This may be faster for situations where you know there will be no emoji input, but I would STRONGLY avoid using this in any production code.

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in the answer this was done only for a Leetcode problem, in real work applications the first approach will work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5** 
`let desiredIndex: Int = 7 
 let substring = str[String.Index(encodedOffset: desiredIndex)...]` 
This substring variable will give you the result.  
Simply here Int is converted to Index and then you can split the strings. Unless you will get errors.

Comment: This is wrong. A Character might consist of one or more bytes. It only works with ascii text.