# Migrating to Swift 3 troubles: String.CharacterView corresponding to 'startIndex'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, collections

**Code:**

```
let startIndex = oldString.characters.index(oldString.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location)

let endIndex = String.Characterview corresponding to 'startIndex' .index(startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
```

**Prior to migrating to Swift 3, the above line was:**

```
let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(5)
```

I know the docs say that `advancedBy` should be converted to:

```
Collection.index(index, offsetBy: delta)
```

but when I do the above code I get this error:

> Protocol Collection can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

**Question:**

So what is it that I need to do here? I feel like this is something simple and I'm just barley missing it. I've been all over the docs and the internet.

Comment: Hi there. There's an extensive discussion of this topic at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677330/how-does-substring-work-in-swift-3 which I think will help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you could get `String.Index` by using these method:

- `startIndex`
- `endIndex`
- `index(before: String.Index)`
- `index(after: String.Index)`
- `index(i: String.Index, offsetBy: String.IndexDistance)`
- `index(i: String.Index, offsetBy: String.IndexDistance, limitedBy: String.Index)`

then you can use `String.substring` as usual.

```
let testStr = "1234567890abcdefghij"

//string length
let testStrLengh = testStr.characters.count

//get tail 10 characters
let tail1 = testStr[testStr.index(testStr.endIndex, offsetBy: -10)..<testStr.endIndex]
let tail2 = testStr.substring(from: testStr.index(testStr.endIndex, offsetBy: -10))

//get head 10 characters
let head1 = testStr[testStr.startIndex..<testStr.index(testStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 10)]
let head2 = testStr.substring(to: testStr.index(testStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 10))

//get centre 10 characters
let startIndex = testStr.index(testStr.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
let endIndex = testStr.index(testStr.endIndex, offsetBy: -5)
let centreStr = testStr.substring(with: startIndex..<endIndex)
```

Comment: So I basically did 'oldString.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 5)'

I think that's what I wanted?

Comment: 'oldString.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 5)' gives a five-bits string starts from `startIndex`. If thats what you want, yes it is.