# Finding new line character in a String in "Swift 3"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

In my app I am receiving some incoming data from a web service. In that data some wrong values can also be received like new line characters. I want to find in response string that if it contains a new line character or not.

**Before Swift 3** I was able to do it like this

```
string.rangeOfString("\n")) == nil)
```

But in **Swift 3** this methods is no longer available. However `substring` method is available which does with the help of `Range`.

I want to detect if my string contains `"\n"` how this would be accomplished using this method in **Swift 3**.

Comment: extension String {
    var lines: [String] {
        var result: [String] = []
        enumerateLines { line, _ in result.append(line) }
        return result
    }
}

Comment: let text = "line1\nline2"
let array = text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines) use this things.

Comment: please check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677330/how-does-string-substring-work-in-swift-3

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I received a new Line Character in response in whole when wrong value is received. So, I just want to detect if it's a new line or not.

Comment: then  text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines) in this you got it . and ya if you want only for check new line availble or not then check array.count > 0 that means new line or else part no new line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to know if it is there and don't care where it is, `string.contains("\n")` will return true if it is there and false if not.

Comment: You are right. It's very simple and elegant built in method

Answer (score 7):

### Short answer for Swift 5+

You can use

```swift
string.contains { $0.isNewline }
```

or KeyPath based syntax

```swift
string.contains(where: \.isNewline)
```

to detect if string contains *any* newline character.

---

### Long answer

Swift 5 introduced couple of new properties on `Character`. Those simplify such tests and are more robust then simple check for `\n`.

Now you can use

```swift
myCharacter.isNewline
```

For complete list check [Inspecting a Character section in `Character` docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character)

Example:

```
Character("\n").isNewline // true
Character("\r").isNewline // true
Character("a").isNewline  // false
```

---

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
yourString.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.newlines) != nil
```

which is more elegant as it's not using harcoded newline character string

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

```
string.range(of: "\n")
```

To check:

```
if string.range(of: "\n") == nil{

}
```

Or if you simply want to check the `string` contains `\n` or not, Then,

```
if !str.characters.contains("\n") {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.characters.contains()` should do the trick:

```
let s1 = "Hi I'm a string\n with a new line"
s1.characters.contains("\n")  // => true

let s2 = "I'm not"
s2.characters.contains("\n")  // => false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let string:String = "This is a string"
if string.range(of: "\n") == nil {
    print  ("contains nil")
}
else {
    print("contains new line")
}
```

perferctly working in swift 3.