# 'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with a CountableClosedRange<Int>, see the documentation comment for discussion

Tags: swift, string, swift4, subscript

In Swift 4, I'm getting this error when I try to take a `Substring` of a `String` using subscript syntax.

> 'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with a CountableClosedRange, see the documentation comment for discussion

For example:

```
let myString: String = "foobar"
let mySubstring: Substring = myString[1..<3]
```

Two questions:

1. How can I resolve this error?
2. Where is "the documentation comment for discussion" that was referred to in the error?

Comment: @KrisRoofe Somebody correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this is due to Extended Grapheme Clusters used to achieve native Unicode support. The swift Strings and Characters documentation states: 

>Every instance of Swift’s Character type represents a single extended grapheme cluster. An extended grapheme cluster is a sequence of one or more Unicode scalars that (when combined) produce a single human-readable character.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html

Comment: You should make simple things simple and complicated things possible. Many times Apple makes simple things complicated in order to make complicated things possible.

Comment: I hope Apple make string[0] become possible in the future.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

1. If you want to use subscripts on Strings like `"palindrome"[1..<3]` and `"palindrome"[1...3]`, use these extensions.

**Swift 4**

```swift
extension String {
    subscript (bounds: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.lowerBound)
        let end = index(startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.upperBound)
        return String(self[start...end])
    }

    subscript (bounds: CountableRange<Int>) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.lowerBound)
        let end = index(startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.upperBound)
        return String(self[start..<end])
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**

For Swift 3 replace with `return self[start...end]` and `return self[start..<end]`.

2. Apple didn't build this into the Swift language because the definition of a 'character' depends on how the String is encoded. A character can be 8 to 64 bits, and the default is usually UTF-16. You can specify other String encodings in `String.Index`.

[This is the documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/b8401e1fde52d95e5a8ce7b043a3c5a3bcf72181/stdlib/public/core/UnavailableStringAPIs.swift.gyb#L15) that Xcode error refers to.

[More on String encodings like UTF-8 and UTF-16](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

Comment: All good, except that you should have used just `bounds.upperBound` instead of `bounds.upperBound - bounds.lowerBound` as `offsetBy` parameter.

Comment: Offset should be `bounds.upperBound - bounds.lowerBound`. 

We expect `"Palindrome"[3..<4]` to give "i".

But if we try `let end = index(start, offsetBy: bounds.upperBound)`, we'll get "indr" instead.

Comment: My point here is that you want `startIndex` and `endIndex` to be indices, i.e. positions of characters in a string, not distances between the characters.

Comment: Sorry, please discard the previous comment, I've accidentally pressed the button that should not have been pressed. Anyway, I see your point now. I was confused because you use `self.startIndex` parameter to initialize `startIndex` and `startIndex` parameter to initialize `endIndex`. If you use `self.startIndex` for both your bounds, you'll be able to just use `bounds.upperBound` for the end index offset. It would even be better to choose names different from String variables `startIndex` and `endIndex` for clarity. This will also allow you to drop all the `self` references.

Comment: Are there changes for Swift 5?

Comment: This could be improved with `let end = index(start, offsetBy: bounds.count)` instead of traversing from the beginning of the string twice. `let end = index(start, offsetBy: bounds.count-1)` in the `CountableClosedRange` case. `index` is O(n) where n is the offset from i

Comment: even better this could be placed in an extension of `StringProtocol` and be applicable to Substrings, etc.

Comment: You'll also need to add an extension that takes a CountablePartialRangeFrom<Int> if you'd like to write e.g. s[2...].

Comment: It is not a solution. Swift also has "open ranges" like `1...`

Comment: Note that this will unnecessarily offset twice from the startIndex instead of just offsetting the range count from the resulting start to get the end. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24144365/2303865

Answer (score 31):

Your question (and self-answer) has 2 problems:

Subscripting a string with `Int` has never been available in Swift's Standard Library. This code has been invalid for as long as Swift exists:

```
let mySubstring: Substring = myString[1..<3]
```

The new `String.Index(encodedOffset: )` returns an index in UTF-16 (16-bit) encoding. Swift's string uses *Extended Grapheme Cluster*, which can take between 8 and 64 bits to store a character. Emojis make for very good demonstration:

```
let myString = ""
let lowerBound = String.Index(encodedOffset: 1)
let upperBound = String.Index(encodedOffset: 3)
let mySubstring = myString[lowerBound..<upperBound]

// Expected: Canadian and UK flags
// Actual  : gibberish
print(mySubstring)
```

---

In fact, getting the `String.Index` has not changed at all in Swift 4, for better or worse:

```
let myString = ""
let lowerBound = myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let upperBound = myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
let mySubstring = myString[lowerBound..<upperBound]

print(mySubstring)
```

Answer (score 20):

You could just convert your string to an array of characters...

```
let aryChar = Array(myString)
```

Then you get all the array functionality...

Comment: And then convert to String back? This solution is so so

Comment: Just for completeness, map works fine too: "Hello World".map{$0}[6] // 'W'

Answer (score 15):

> 1. How can I resolve this error?

This error means you can't use an Int in the subscript format – you have to use a String.Index, which you can initialize with an encodedOffset Int.

```
let myString: String = "foobar"
let lowerBound = String.Index.init(encodedOffset: 1)
let upperBound = String.Index.init(encodedOffset: 3)
let mySubstring: Substring = myString[lowerBound..<upperBound]
```

> 2. Where is "the documentation comment for discussion" that was referred to in the error?

It's on GitHub in the Swift Standard Library repository in a file called UnavailableStringAPIs.swift.gyb in the bottom of a locked filing cabinet stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying 'Beware of the Leopard'. [link](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/b8401e1fde52d95e5a8ce7b043a3c5a3bcf72181/stdlib/public/core/UnavailableStringAPIs.swift.gyb#L15)

Comment: Don't use `encodedOffset` here; it doesn't necessarily correspond to characters, it (currently) corresponds to UTF-16 code units (which just *happens* to be characters for ASCII strings). For example, with `let myString = "hello"`, `mySubstring` is just `` (because that's encoded with 2 UTF-16 code units). With `let myString = "hello"`, the subscripting raises a runtime error, as `` is encoded with 4 UTF-16 code units. Instead of using `encodedOffset:`, use `myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)`; which talks in terms of characters.

Comment: (also note that `String`'s ranged subscript returns `Substring`, not `String` in Swift 4)

Comment: @Hamish What if I want my lowerBound to be something higher than myString.startIndex? I've updated the example to not start at 0. I suppose I could initialize a Range using init(uncheckedBounds: (lower:upper:)) and take its lower and upper bounds. I've updated the example regarding Substring.

Comment: To get an index at offset 1, you can say `let lowerBound = myString.index(myString.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)` or `let lowerBound = myString.index(after: myString.startIndex)`.

Comment: I get the Hitchiker's Guide reference :)

Answer (score 6):

Based on [p-sun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46627527/4188011)

**Swift 4**

```
extension StringProtocol {
    subscript(bounds: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.lowerBound)
        let end = index(start, offsetBy: bounds.count)
        return self[start..<end]
    }

    subscript(bounds: CountableRange<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.lowerBound)
        let end = index(start, offsetBy: bounds.count)
        return self[start..<end]
    }
}
```

Notable changes:

- Now an extension of `StringProtocol`. This allows adopters such as `Substring` to also gain these subscripts.
- End indices are offset from the start index of the bounds rather than the start of the string. This prevents traversing from the start of the `String` twice. The `index` method is O(n) where n is the offset from i.

Comment: Definitely an improvement on the accepted answer IMHO. You could also use `max(0, bounds.lowerBound)` as the `offsetBy` parameter when calculating the `start` index to ensure that you don't accidentally try to access a negative index.

Comment: I personally would prefer that to fail, as that is a developer error. Out of bound errors are expected with invalid indexes. If they are fixed silently I wouldn't catch the mistake.

Comment: Why both methods are exactly the same... shouldn't one be ..< and second ... ?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski No, because the endIndex of the input already accounts for the difference.

Answer (score 4):

## 2022

Improved code of [p-sun's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46627527/709202) and [Justin Oroz's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55659545/709202) answers:

Code works with `SubSequence`s, so it's uses less memory.

You're able to do:

```
// works well even on substrings
"01234567890"[i: 1]  // Character "1"
"01234567890"[i: 15] // nil

"01234567890"[safe: 1..<5] // subsequence "1234"
"01234567890"[safe: 1...5] // subsequence "12345"
"012"[safe: 1..<15]        // subsequence "12"
"012"[safe: 1...15]        // subsequence "12"


"012"[unsafe: 1..<9]       // will thrown FatalError OutOfBounds exception
"012"[unsafe: 1...9]       // will thrown FatalError OutOfBounds exception
"012"[unsafe: -1..<2]      // will thrown FatalError OutOfBounds exception
"012"[unsafe: -1...2]      // will thrown FatalError OutOfBounds exception
```

```
public extension StringProtocol {
    subscript(i idx: Int) -> Character? {
        if idx >= self.count { return nil }
        
        return self[self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: idx)]
    }
}

public extension Substring {
    subscript(i idx: Int) -> Character? {
        if idx >= self.count { return nil }
        return self.base[index(startIndex, offsetBy: idx)]
    }
}

public extension StringProtocol {
    /// Use this if you want to get OutOfBounds exception
    subscript(unsafe bounds: Range<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        let startIndex = index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.lowerBound)
        return self[startIndex..<index(startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.count)]
    }
    
    /// Use this if you want to get OutOfBounds exception
    subscript(unsafe bounds: ClosedRange<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        let startIndex = index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.lowerBound)
        return self[startIndex..<index(startIndex, offsetBy: bounds.count)]
    }
}

public extension String {
    /// Use this if you want to get result with any incorrect input
    subscript(safe bounds: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        let lowerBound = max(0, Int(bounds.lowerBound) )
        
        guard lowerBound < self.count else { return "" }
        
        let upperBound = min(Int(bounds.upperBound), self.count-1)
        
        guard upperBound >= 0 else { return "" }
        
        let minIdx = index(startIndex, offsetBy: lowerBound )
        let maxIdx = index(minIdx, offsetBy: upperBound-lowerBound )
        
        return self[minIdx...maxIdx]
    }
    
    /// Use this if you want to get result with any incorrect input
    subscript(safe bounds: CountableRange<Int>) -> SubSequence {
        let lowerBound = max(0, bounds.lowerBound)
        
        guard lowerBound < self.count else { return "" }
        
        let upperBound = min(bounds.upperBound, self.count)
        
        guard upperBound >= 0 else { return "" }
        
        let minIdx = index(startIndex, offsetBy: lowerBound )
        let maxIdx = index(minIdx, offsetBy: upperBound-lowerBound )
        
        return self[minIdx..<maxIdx]
    }
}
```

Code is tested:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Building on both [p-sun's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46627527/709202) and [Justin Oroz's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55659545/709202) answers, here are two extensions that protect against invalid indexes beyond the start and end of a string (these extensions also avoid rescanning the string from the beginning just to find the index at the end of the range):

```
extension String {

    subscript(bounds: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> String {
        let lowerBound = max(0, bounds.lowerBound)
        guard lowerBound < self.count else { return "" }

        let upperBound = min(bounds.upperBound, self.count-1)
        guard upperBound >= 0 else { return "" }

        let i = index(startIndex, offsetBy: lowerBound)
        let j = index(i, offsetBy: upperBound-lowerBound)

        return String(self[i...j])
    }

    subscript(bounds: CountableRange<Int>) -> String {
        let lowerBound = max(0, bounds.lowerBound)
        guard lowerBound < self.count else { return "" }

        let upperBound = min(bounds.upperBound, self.count)
        guard upperBound >= 0 else { return "" }

        let i = index(startIndex, offsetBy: lowerBound)
        let j = index(i, offsetBy: upperBound-lowerBound)

        return String(self[i..<j])
    }
}
```

Comment: you can simply use the range count https://stackoverflow.com/a/24144365/2303865

Answer (score -2):

```
extension String {

    subscript(bounds: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> String {
        let lowerBound = max(0, bounds.lowerBound)
        guard lowerBound < self.count else { return "" }

        let upperBound = min(bounds.upperBound, self.count-1)
        guard upperBound >= 0 else { return "" }

        let i = index(startIndex, offsetBy: lowerBound)
        let j = index(i, offsetBy: upperBound-lowerBound)

        return String(self[i...j])
    }

    subscript(bounds: CountableRange<Int>) -> String {
        let lowerBound = max(0, bounds.lowerBound)
        guard lowerBound < self.count else { return "" }

        ***let upperBound = min(bounds.upperBound, self.count-1)***
        guard upperBound >= 0 else { return "" }

        let i = index(startIndex, offsetBy: lowerBound)
        let j = index(i, offsetBy: upperBound-lowerBound)

        return String(self[i..<j])
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift 5 - doesn't work with "open" ranges. Additionally what does your `***` mean?

Answer (score -2):

You getting this error because result of subscript with range is 
`Substring?` not `Substring`.

You must use following code:

```
let myString: String = "foobar"
let mySubstring: Substring? = myString[1..<3]
```

Comment: Subscripting a `string` with `Int` has never been available in Swift's Standard Library. It's using `String.Index` as input. The same is about range of Int ofc. So this code has been invalid for as long as Swift exists.