# Swift string equality

Tags: arrays, swift, string, string-comparison

I am new at swift language and I need to compare some strings or some characters in any string.

first question:
The last version of swift doesn't allow equal operation == like this.

```
if "1" == item.index(item.startIndex, offsetBy: 7){
     print("ok!")
}
```

item is a string, it has this string "01: 06-08-2017, 13:43" (I can see its inside when I write print)

How can I check some characters in any string?

Comment: Well, this is gonna get frustrating pretty quickly for you, but I assure you that Strings in Swift has the current implementation for a good reason (Unicode Compatibility). Try giving [Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) a read (focus on "Accessing and Modifying a String" for now) and hopefully that'll make things a bit easier to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3:**

For comparing with one character, you could achieve this simply by [*String.CharacterView*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string.characterview):

> In Swift, every string provides a **view of its contents as characters**.
>   In this view, many individual characters—for example, “é”, “김”, and
>   “”—can be made up of multiple Unicode code points. These code
>   points are combined by Unicode’s boundary algorithms into extended
>   grapheme clusters, represented by the Character type. Each element of
>   a CharacterView collection is a Character instance.

You can simply cast it as an array and check the desired character based on its index:

```
let item = "01: 06-08-2017, 13:43"

if "1" == Array(item.characters)[1] {
    print("matched")
}
```

And for more that one character, you could generate a *range* to substring:

```
let item = "01: 06-08-2017, 13:43"

// assuming we will get "06-08-2017"
let range = item.index(item.startIndex, offsetBy: 4) ..< item.index(item.startIndex, offsetBy: 14)

if "06-08-2017" == item.substring(with: range) {
    print("matched")
}
```

For more information about substring, I recommend to check [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677330/how-does-string-substring-work-in-swift-3).

Answer (score 1):

The mistake in your code is that the type of `item.index(item.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)` is not a `String`, nor a `Character`. It's of type `String.Index` (in Swift 3, it's an alias of `String.CharacterView.Index`), which holds just a position in a `String` and does not represent any sort of contents in a `String`.

Your code in question would be rewritten as:

```
let item = "01: 06-08-2017, 13:43"

if item[item.index(item.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)] == "1" {
    print("ok!")
} else {
    print("invalid") //->invalid
}
```

You can subscript (`[]`) to a `String` with `String.Index` and get a `Character` at the position, and compare it to a `Character`. (In this context, `"1"` is treated as a `Character`, not `String`.)

Subscript for `String` works also with `Range<String.Index>`:

```
let startIndex = item.index(item.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
let endIndex = item.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 10)

if item[startIndex..<endIndex] == "06-08-2017" {
    print("hit!") //->hit!
}
```

---

In Swift 4, many things around `String` type have changed, but the code above should work both in Swift 3 & 4.