# Search and extract substring in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

Relatively new to Swift programming.

I get an dictionary from which I need to get the user name (first and last name) and display it in table view cell along with other data.

On iPhone 5 and below as the screen width is only 320, the requirement is to just display the first name and first character of the last name.

E.g: "Howard Mark" to "Howard M"

I am sure that there is an elegant way to extract the required string.

```
struct ScreenSize
{
    static let SCREEN_WIDTH = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    static let SCREEN_HEIGHT = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
}

struct DeviceType
{
    static let IS_IPHONE_5_OR_LESS = (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH <= 568.0)
}

func functionCall (referralData:[String: Any?])
{
    var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()


    if var nameString = referralData[KEY_FULL_NAME]
        {

              if  DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_5_OR_LESS
              {
                var a = nameString as? NSString

                var arr = a?.components(separatedBy: " ")

                let newStr = arr?[0] as? String
                nameString = newStr
                if((arr?.count)! > 1)
                {
                    if let secondString = arr?[1]
                    {
                        let newStr2 = newStr as? NSString

                        let secondChar = newStr2?.character(at: 0)
                        let stringchar:String! = String(secondChar!)
                        nameString = "\(newStr!) \(stringchar)"
                    }
                }

                print("iPhone 5 or less")
            }
            else
            {
                print("Greater than iPhone 5")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related but why do you cast non-optional `nameString` to optional `NSString`? And why do you annotate a non-optional string `stringchar` to a implicit unwrapped optional string?

Comment: `I get an dictionary from which I need to get the user name (first and last name) ` — are first and last name separated in the source dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think anyone should be thinking in Swift 3 any more. Here's a Swift 4 example:

```
var name = "Veeblefetzer Rumplestiltskin"
if let r = name.range(of: " ", options: .backwards, range: name.startIndex..<name.endIndex) {
    name = String(name[name.startIndex..<name.index(r.upperBound, offsetBy: 1)])
}
name // "Veeblefetzer R"
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this?

```
let fullName = "Dominik Pich"
var parts = fullName.components(separatedBy: " ")

if parts.count > 0,
  let lastNameInitial = parts.last?.prefix(1) {
  parts[parts.count-1] = String(lastNameInitial)
}

let truncatedName = parts.joined(separator: " ")

//use
print("fullName: \(fullName)")
print("truncatedName: \(truncatedName)")
```

---

I'd wrap it in a nice String extension - e.g. a computed property `truncateLast`

Answer (score 0):

The most helpful answer I've found when using Swift's built in substring command is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39677331/5495979

Although, using the substring command still requires you to first obtain a range or an index, so it still requires a couple commands to implement.

So Using my preferred method from the SO answer referenced above I would just grab the index of the first character and use the substring command and cast it to a string:

```
let index = secondString.index(secondString.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)
let stringChar = String(secondString.substring(to: index))
```

I also wanted to let you know that there appears to be a logic error in your code when obtaining the first letter of the last name.  You unwrap what should be the last name in your string components array with `if let secondString = arr?[1]` but then don't assign the unwrapped string stored in `secondString` to `newStr2` before parsing `newStr2` for the first character in the string. As it appears now when you parse the first character of the string with `let secondChar = newStr2?.character(at: 0)` you will actually be parsing the first character from the first name (since when assigning newStr2 with `let newStr2 = newStr as? NSString` you are actually assigning the fist entry from the array of name strings since newStr is only assinged  with `let newStr = arr?[0] as? String`)