# Creating A Substring | Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, substring

How do I substring a string in swift 4.

I would like to convert:

> "Hello, World!"

Into:

> "Hello"

Answer (score -3):

Swift has no built in function to make this easy so I wrote a simple extension to get the same functionality as other languages such as python which have really easy substring functions.

**Extension**

Outside your class, add this extension for strings.

```
extension String {
    func substring(start: Int, range: Int) -> String {
        let characterArray = Array(self)
        var tempArray:[Character] = []
        let starting = start
        let ending = start + range
        for i in (starting...ending) {
            tempArray.append(characterArray[i])
        }
        let finalString = String(tempArray)
        return finalString
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let myString = "Hello, World!"
print(myString.substring(start: 0, range: 4))
```

This prints:

> "Hello"

**How It Works**

The extension works by turning the string into an array of separate characters then creates a loop which appends the desired characters into a new string which is determined by the function's parameters.

Thanks for stopping by. I hope apple add this basic functionality to their language soon! The above code is a bit messy so if anyone wants to clean it up then feel free!

Comment: Who told you that it hasn't ??

Comment: Well, no basic substring function such as python has. I thought this would be useful for beginners such as myself

Comment: If your range is 4 you should get Hell not Hello

Comment: Btw naming range the length is misleading

Comment: Have a look at the various answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/39677330/1187415 (of which your question is a duplicate) or https://stackoverflow.com/q/24092884/1187415 for more efficient solutions.

Comment: Even if we decided to use the array od characters, this would be too complicated. Why ti copy chars one by one instead of just taking the subarray?