# How to make some text or words invisible or visible in the cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to make some words in the cell invisible or visible. This is my code below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? TableViewCell


    var dic = ar[indexPath.row]
    cell!.cell0.text = dic["date0"]
```

...

`cell!.cell0.text` has "Helloworld"

I need "Helloworld" for later so I can't get only "world" from `dic["date0"]`.

I would like to make only "world" visible in the table view.

Is there anyone who can help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: Use attributed string. This can help you to define a range  and colour for your text in different ways. See this for example https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-to-set-use-multiple-font-colors-in.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that link does not seem to be directly relevant to my question...

Comment: Actually you can split your strings or proceed  with range...

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for are Substrings.

```
let string = "Helloworld"

let beginningText = String(string.suffix(5)) //world
let endText = String(string.prefix(5)) //Hello

let start = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let end = string.index(string.endIndex, offsetBy: -3)
let range = start..<end

let middleText = String(string[range]) //ellowo
```

For more information, refer to this answer on a different question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39677331/3127261)

Comment: I can't save only "world" part in the cell!.cello.text. I have to send the whole text to other method(or function). I just want to make that part visible.

Comment: Is making a custom cell not a possible solution in your case? I would create a new class that extends UITableViewCell and give it a property in which you can store "Helloworld" or other values.

Answer (score -1):

In the cell class you can so like so:

```
 var str = "Helloworld"// for example

 var splitString  = str.components(separatedBy: "Hello")

 self.label.text = splitString
```

Comment: I don't have a variable "label" here

Comment: If you want to show something in a cell you need to put some outlets in the cell view.
For example put a label in the cell connect it to the cell class and then you will get it like this:

                      let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! SomeCellClass


cell.label.text = "string"

Answer (score -3):

Check out *isHidden*


With *isHiddem* you can choose with a Boolean value if you want to show the text or not


https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622585-ishidden

Comment: I tried before like cell!.cell1.isHidden = true but I would like to make the text partially hidden