# Return substring from attributed string using range in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, range, substring, nsrange

I am trying to get a substring from a string using the range without luck. Having searched high and low, I can't find a way to do this seemingly straightforward task in Swift. The range is in the form of an NSRange obtained from a delegate method.

In Objective-c, if you have a range, you could do:

```
NSString * text = "Hello World";
NSString *sub = [text substringWithRange:range];
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677330/how-does-string-substring-work-in-swift), the following should work in Swift:

```
let mySubstring = text[range]  // play
let myString = String(mySubstring)
```

However, when I try this, I get an error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type
>   'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange')

I think the issue may have to do with using an NSRange instead of a range but I can't figure out how to get it to work.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is you can not subscript a `String` using a `NSRange`, you have to use a `Range`. Try the following out:

```
let newRange = Range(range, in: text)
let mySubstring = text[newRange]
let myString = String(mySubstring)
```

Comment: Swift 4 you can use the new Range initializer `init?(_ range: NSRange, in string: String)`. In this case  `let newRange = Range(range, in: text)`

Comment: Cool, didn't now that, just edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please read your linked question one more time.

You will notice that String in Swift doesn't work with `Range<Int>` but with `Range<String.Index>` and definitely not with `NSRange`

Example of using range on string:

```swift
let text = "Hello world"
let from = text.index(after: text.startIndex)
let to = text.index(from, offsetBy: 4)
text[from...to] // ello
```