# 'subscript(_:)' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, use a String.Index instead

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitableview

I'm trying to pass the data and got this error: `'subscript(_:)' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, use a String.Index instead.` Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: CustomLoopsCell = beatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstLoopCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomLoopsCell
        
        let beatLoop = overtunePacks[indexPath.row]

        // On the lines which is down I'm getting this error
        let beatDesc = loopsDesc[indexPath.row]
        let beatProd = loopsProd[indexPath.row]
        let beatAudio = loopsAudio[indexPath.row] 
        let beatInst = loopsInst[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.loopNameLabel.text = beatDesc
        cell.producerLabel.text = beatProd
        cell.instrumentLabel.text = beatInst
```

Here is the code from another view controller, from where I'm passing the data:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "BeatViewID") as? BeatPackViewController
    vc?.beatInfoCollectName = beatInfoCollect[indexPath.row].name
    vc?.beatProducerName = beatInfoCollect[indexPath.row].producer
    vc?.imageBeat = beatInfoCollect[indexPath.row].imagename
    vc?.loopsAudio = beatAudioCollect[indexPath.row].loopPath
    vc?.loopsDesc = beatAudioCollect[indexPath.row].name
    vc?.loopsInst = beatAudioCollect[indexPath.row].instrument
    vc?.loopsProd = beatAudioCollect[indexPath.row].producer
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}
```

Here is my variables in second view controller, where I'm passing data:

```
var loopsAudio = ""
    var loopsDesc = ""
    var loopsInst = ""
    var loopsProd = ""
```

Here is what I want to display:

```
struct BeatLoops: Decodable {
        let name: String
        let instrument: String
        let loopPath: String
        let producer: String
        
        var songURL : URL {
            let components = loopPath.components(separatedBy: ".")
            guard components.count == 2,
                  let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: components[0], withExtension: components[1]) else { fatalError("Audio file is missing") }
            return url
        }
    }
```

I'm parsing this data and have instance: `var beatAudioCollect = [BeatLoops]()`

Comment: Did you check these related questions? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+cannot+subscript+String+with+an+Int

Comment: Yes, but there is no answer for my problem

Comment: You need to update your question include the declaration of the variables that are causing the problem. I would also suggest updating your question to include a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Check, I've updated

Comment: You probably want to get a value from an array by index rather than from a string (a single **character**)

Comment: Cant understand what you mean

Comment: For example If `loopsDesc` is `Foo` then you'll get `F` for indexPath.row 0, `o` for indexPath.row 1 and also `o` for indexPath.row 2. This is certainly not what you want. You might add the information what you want to display in the second view controller. It looks like a single object so another table view is not needed.

Comment: I want to display data from JSON, I will update the code now

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you are trying to get Substring from a *loopsDesc* String here

```
let beatDesc = loopsDesc[indexPath.row]
...
let beatInst = loopsInst[indexPath.row]
```

The point is that you can't just get String's characters using subscription index.

If you want to get a character from a String, you should get it's Substring with a specified range.

Like that:

```
let index = loopsDesc.index(loopsDesc.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let mySubstring = loopsDesc[..<index]
```

Or another way:

1 - add this extension to a String:

```
extension StringProtocol {
subscript(offset: Int) -> Character {
    self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)]
  }
}
```

2 - use it like that

```
let input = "My String Here"
let char = input[3]
//or
let char = String(input[3])
```

Please see another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677330/how-does-string-substring-work-in-swift) related to that.

But it's unsafe method and I would suggest to use another way to get params (for example store them in Array, not in String)

Comment: As you can see, I'm passing data from the first view controller to the variables which I have created in second view controller.

Comment: your error is not about passing data, it is about accessing the  
 `loopsDesc[indexPath.row]` where 
`indexPath.row` is an Int. As mentioned by "Roman Shinyavski" answer, you cannot do that.
You need to use a "special" index just for strings, not a Int. Read the error message, it tells you what to do.  Look at the docs for `Accessing and Modifying a String` in swift 
at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html

Comment: I think you don't understand what I want, only to pass data from the structure

Comment: you mean you don't get the error that you showing us?

Comment: I'm getting only this error which I've wrote in this question

Comment: well then, this answer tells you how to fix it. Does it work for you? If not what other error are you getting?

Comment: This answer is not correct, only Vadian answer showing the some part of the solution

Answer (score 0):

**Your design is wrong.**

Extracting single characters from a string in a table view to be displayed in different rows makes no sense.

Actually you are passing two objects to the second view controller, an *`infoCollect`* object and an *`audioCollect`* object.

First of all rather than extracting all properties just pass the entire objects.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "BeatViewID") as! BeatPackViewController
    vc.infoCollect = beatInfoCollect[indexPath.row]
    vc.audioCollect = beatAudioCollect[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

By the way using multiple arrays as data source is strongly discouraged!.

---

In the second controller replace the `String` properties with

```
var infoCollect : Loop!
var audioCollect : BeatLoops!
```

If the structs are declared inside in first view controller you have to write

```
var infoCollect : BPLibraryViewController.Loop!
var audioCollect : BPLibraryViewController.BeatLoops!
```

Then remove the table view and add `UILabel`s instead. In `viewDidLoad` assign the values for example

```
imageBeatLabel.text = infoCollect.name
loopsAudioLabel.text = audioCollect.loopPath
```

Comment: On this line: vc?.audioCollect = beatAudioCollect[indexPath.row] - I'm getting an error: Cannot assign value of type 'BPLibraryViewController.BeatLoops' to type 'BeatLoops'

Comment: You have to declare the proper matching type. I just guessed what it is.

Comment: Proper matching type, what do you mean?

Comment: Te proper type of `beatInfoCollect` and `beatAudioCollect`

Comment: Now they are: var beatInfoCollect = [Loop]()
    var beatAudioCollect = [BeatLoops]()

Comment: I'm getting an error: Value of type 'BPLibraryViewController.BeatLoops' has no member 'count' When I've tried this: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return audioCollect.count
    }

Comment: Please read my answer. As I said, **remove  the table view**. It's not needed. The data is static

Comment: But I need that it will be in table view, if I will remove what it will be?

Comment: According to your `didSelectRowAt` method you are going to display 7 (static) values in the second view controller. So replace the table view with 7 labels.

Comment: Not like this. At the first view controller I have a table view and there is 4 cells. And when I tap on each of them, it pass data to the second view controller using this methods.